# Is there any way I can use the webpack to save edits to files in the original path while I can debug as well?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webpack, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way I can use the webpack to save edits to files in the original path while I can debug as well?

When I edit js files in webpack:///. using and save it chrome says: "Changes to file were not saved to file system".

I already set devtool: 'inline-source-map' on webpack config file.

[chrome-dev-tools warning printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxKpY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar question to yours. Here's how I resolved it.
[Cannot use Chrome Live Edit with Webpack source maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53806276/cannot-use-chrome-live-edit-with-webpack-source-maps)

Something to note. After I save my edits, I still get the same yellow icon saying it wasn't able to save, but it DID save my changes to my source maps.

Hope this helps!