# Cannot use Chrome Live Edit with Webpack source maps

Tags: google-chrome, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I have a webpack 4 configuration that generates source maps for my app's JavaScript. While debugging my app in Chrome, the source maps get loaded so I can see my unimified code. I'll set a breakpoint in a function and in the Sources tab I'll make edits to the code. I hit CMD+S to save my edits.

Normally, I would expect Chrome to think for a little bit while it processes my edits and then I can continue debugging my session with my code changes.

But that doesn't happen. I get a little yellow icon next to my file in the Sources tab that says *"Changes to this file were not saved to the filesystem"*. And the debugging session continues without my code changes.

I've tried different options like `cheap-module-source-map` and `cheap-module-eval-source-map` for the `devtools` option in my webpack config.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got something working!

I ended up posting my same question on reddit and got some help.
https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/a98gh1/cannot_use_chrome_live_edit_with_webpack_source/

> You need to add your project's directory to save changes in the
>   source.
>
> Here are the steps:
>
> Open dev tools
>
> Click on the 3 vertical dots on the far-right beside X which brings up
>   a menu. Click on Settings
>
> Click on Workspace
>
> Add your Project's directory
>
> Refresh the page, and you should be able to save your changes now.
>
> Hope this helps.

Oddly enough, I was able to remove my Project's directory from the Workspace and STILL able to make Live Edits to my source maps!